# Проверка на возрастающую последовательность

Tags: c++, проверка

Сделал проверку на ввод чисел по возрастанию,вот только хотелось сделать так,чтобы если числа введены не по возрастанию,то ввести числа заново. У меня получилось,только не совсем корректно. Проблема с while

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>          
#include <string> 
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
int i = 0;
int u = 0;
const int dequeSize = 10;

//Первый дек   
std::deque<int> myDeque(dequeSize);

cout << "Введите элементы дека" << endl;
for (i = 0; i<dequeSize; i++)
{
    cout << "Введенный дек [" << i << "] = ";
    while(!(cin>>myDeque[i])) 
{
    cout<<"~~~~~~~~~~~~~"<<endl;
    cout<<"ОШИБКА"<<endl;
    cout<<"Введите число:  ";
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cin.clear(); 
    cin.sync();  
}

}



for (i = 0; i < (dequeSize - 1); i++)

    if (myDeque[i] > myDeque[i + 1])
        break;

if (i == (dequeSize - 1)){

    cout << "Sorted";
}else{

    cout << "Not Sorted";

}
while(!(i == (dequeSize - 1))){

    cout << "Введите элементы дека" << endl;
for (i = 0; i<dequeSize; i++)
{
    cout << "Введенный дек [" << i << "] = ";
    while(!(cin>>myDeque[i])) 
{
    cout<<"~~~~~~~~~~~~~"<<endl;
    cout<<"ОШИБКА"<<endl;
    cout<<"Введите число:  ";
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cin.clear(); 
    cin.sync();  
}
}
}
```

---

Вот этой части кода проблема.Мне нужно ,чтобы если ввелся не возрастающий дек,то его нужно было писать заново

```
    for (i = 0; i < (dequeSize - 1); i++)

    if (myDeque[i] > myDeque[i + 1])
        break;

if (i == (dequeSize - 1)){

    cout << "Sorted";
}else{

    cout << "Not Sorted";

}
while(!(i == (dequeSize - 1))){

    cout << "Введите элементы дека" << endl;
for (i = 0; i<dequeSize; i++)
{
    cout << "Введенный дек [" << i << "] = ";
    while(!(cin>>myDeque[i])) 
{
    cout<<"~~~~~~~~~~~~~"<<endl;
    cout<<"ОШИБКА"<<endl;
    cout<<"Введите число:  ";
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cin.clear(); 
    cin.sync();  
}
}
```

Comment: "*Проблема с while*" В чем проблема **конкретно**? С каким из while - из у вас в коде целых три?

Comment: !(cin>>myDeque[i])   это условие не имеет никакой связи с тем, что число больше или меньше предыдущего. Условие всегда будет  иметь значение false, пока вы вводите  целые или  одиночный символ

Comment: while(!(i == (dequeSize - 1))) вот этот

Comment: Мне нужно ,чтобы если ввелся не возрастающий дек,то его нужно было писать заново.

Answer (score 0):

Все это можно вместить в один цикл

```
int size{10};
std::vector<int> arr(size, 0);
int i{};
do {
    cin >> arr[i];
    if (i > 0 && arr[i] < arr[i - 1] {
         i = 0;
    }
    else {
        i++;
    }
} while (i < size);
```

Код не проверял, но вроде должен работать.

Comment: нужно вводить последнее число заново, а не все

Comment: В таком случае заменить i = 0 на i--

Comment: К тому же в вопросе написано именно: ввести числа заново, а не ввести последнее число заново, так что менять ответ не буду.